# Вывести дочернюю категорию указанной категории wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

В wordpress есть создал категорию Publishers.
В ней есть множество подкатегорий. 
Как вывести название название подкатегории к которой принадлежит пост,
внутри категории publishers.

Пока что найден способ вывести только все подкатегории категории Pubishers.
А необходимо конкретно подкатегорию категории к которой пренадлежит пост.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать такую конструкцию. 
Где цифра 8 - это id родительской категории.

```
<?php

    foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(8, $childcat)) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'" class="cat_link">';
    echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>';
    }}
?>
```